# get runtime execution plan of a query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an application that executes some sql queries. How can I get execution plan for currently executing query from sqlplus or some other oracle client? I can amend oracle session that is used in application, if that is necessary.

I do not want to use `explain plan` and execute that query by hand, I need to get actual execution plan that is used for query.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can run explain plain on historical queries from the SGA -[examples](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/format-explain-plan-results-easily-with-oracles-dbmsxplan/6070884)

And listing B.

Example:

```
SELECT username, prev_sql_id
FROM v$session
WHERE username = 'RDEVALL'  -- example user
```

SQL ID returned

```
RDEVALL a1d4z5ruduzrd
RDEVALL avmbutuknvb6j
RDEVALL 75g0tqd9x743y
RDEVALL 5fnkh6c8mqqt3
RDEVALL 75g0tqd9x743y
```

Pick query ID and use here:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR('a1d4z5ruduzrd')); -- replace with sql ID as needed
```

Comment: Also, you can query v$session on other search criteria, like machine name, program name, etc., if that makes more sense in determining which SQL statement to locate. run DESC V$SESSION to see all relevant columns.

Comment: I have a problem with DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR().  
I have two users running the same query in two distinct sessions.  Since the query is the same, the hash key of the query in both session is the same.   When calling DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(<hash key>), how come one does not specify the session?  I believe that this function is returning the planned execution plan, not the actual execution plan running in a specific session.

Comment: @HansDeragon, better you provide example of the same which scenario you are facing. It can help more to understand the situation.