# How much extra computational time is this Oracle query taking?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am working on a pl/sql code. Please help in computational time for the following two methods.

Method 1:

```
if count(x)>1
then
  select sum(price) into vprice from table1 where x between var1 and var2;
else
  select price into vprice from table1 where x=var1;
end;
```

Method 2:

```
select sum(price) from table1 where x between var1 and var2;
```

We are determining the value of var1 and var2 somewhere above the code based on other conditions. In around four out of five cases the value of var1 and var2 will turn out to be same.

P.S.: Please ignore any syntax or logical error. I have tried to give idea of what is happening in my program to know what is the better way to achieve more efficiency.

Comment: Can't you test to find out?

Comment: Method1 appears to execute one of two queries according to some value. `if count(x)>1` is not valid PL/SQL, which I know you said to ignore but I can't tell what it's trying to do. Method2 seems to be similar to the first query in Method1. What the two 'methods' have to do with 'computational time', whatever that is, is not clear.

Comment: I assume you're asking whether the savings from using `=` instead of `between` (if any) are outweighed by the extra PL/SQL logic to decide which branch to follow?

Answer (score 0):

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select sum(price) from table1 where x between var1 and var2;
SELECT * FROM TABLE (dbms_xplan.display); -- take this output and compare it to the next one

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR select price from table1 where x=var1;
SELECT * FROM TABLE (dbms_xplan.display); -- compare it to this output
```

Comment: the above gives the estimated execution plan, to get the actual -- see Alternatively, you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480264/get-runtime-execution-plan-of-a-query

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE
    tsStartTime TIMESTAMP;
    tsEndTime TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    -- Start the timer
    tsStartTime := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tsStartTime);

    -- DO SOMETHING HERE WHICH YOU WANT TO TIME <------

    -- Display some information, and how long "something" took
    tsEndTime := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tsEndTime);

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Time elapsed:' || to_char(tsEndTime - tsStartTime));
END;
/
```